# Interval in Product Space

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

I am reading a paper now that refers to an "interval" in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. But what does interval here refer to? Does this mean there is some ordering of the elements in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$? I am assuming there is some default ordering there, inherited from the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$.

If you have any reference that can help me on this matter, I will appreciate if you share it with me. Thank you.

Comment: Could refer to a collection of constant functions whose values together form an interval.  That's just a guess.  If you post the source I'm sure you will get an answer.

Comment: Maybe the lexicographic order?

Comment: @David I'm sorry I don't have a link to the source. But the source says that "$I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ with dimension $N = \{t_1, t_2,...,t_n \}$." Could it be that $I$ here refers to a product of $n$ intervals in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @youler But how do you define the lexicographic order for sequences indexed by $[0,1]$?

Comment: Wouldn't it go exactly the same as the usual lexicographic order? Sorry, maybe I'm not thinking straight.

Comment: Someone recently said that for some reason an "interval" in $\Bbb R^n$ is typically a product of right-half-open intervals.

Comment: The question cannot be answered without further information. It might be a set of the form $$\left\{h\in\Bbb R^{[0,1]}:\forall x\in[0,1]\Big(f(x)\le h(x)\le g(x)\Big)\right\}\;,$$ where $f,g\in\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ are such that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. It might be as set of the form $\prod_{x\in[0,1]}I_x$, where all but finitely many $I_x=\Bbb R$, and the rest have the form $[\alpha,\beta)$ for some $\alpha<\beta$ in $\Bbb R$. I can think of a couple more possibilities as well.